# Where is the Linux Console Output When Using Remote Debug with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

My Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017) connects to the Linux system successfully with the  following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("hello from ConsoleApplication1!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But, when the code executes, I can't see the "hello from ConsoleApplication1!" message in the VS2017 output window.  Where can I find it?

Comment: See here: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WritingAndDebuggingLinuxCApplicationsFromVisualStudioUsingTheWindowsSubsystemForLinux.aspx  It looks like that output is available in the "Linux Console Window".

Comment: My VS2017 didn't show the Linux Console Window, how can I find it out?

Comment: My question is the same with this one: "Visual Studio 2017 RC4: Console Output is gone", there is no Linux Console Window in Visual Studio 2017 RC4.

Answer (score 15):

I find it at last: Debug menu: Linux console

Answer (score 8):

For those who don't find "Linux Console" under Debug menu:

What happen to me was that I had one solution with 2 projects- Console App (Windows) and Linux Console App.
The Windows was set as the start up project, and I debugged the Linux project by right-clicking the project->Debug->Start New Instance.
I couldn't find the Linux Condole Window anywhere even when debugging.

[image]

After setting the Linux project as the startup project it appeared in the Debug menu:

[image]

Afterwards I changed it back and kept the Linux Console Window Open. 
It's an ugly hack and I hope that Visual Studio will change it (I'm using VS 2019 16.1.3)