# Show interactive console for multiple docker containers in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-2017

I am currently developing a .Net Core-project with multiple docker containers, 2 are .NET Core Console Applications, the third is RabbitMQ.

**My target is to open a console window where I can press enter for at least one of the console applications running in the docker containers.**

I added docker-support by right-clicking my console applications and clicking "Add => Docker Support".

This is my docker-compose-file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: service1
    build:
      context: ./Service1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
     - "rabbitmq:rabbit"
  service2:
    image: service2
    build:
      context: ./Service2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
     - "rabbitmq:rabbit"
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
     - "8082:15672"
     - "5672:5672"
```

This is my docker-compose-override.yml:
`version: '3'`

But Visual Studio does the following overrides when running the Service2-container:

```
Service2:
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
      context: C:\Develop\vsts_tfs\Service2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES: /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
    image: service2:dev
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: ' --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages
        --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Service2.dll'
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: /bin/bash -c "if PID=$(pidof
        -x dotnet); then kill $PID; fi"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: dotnet
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: /app
    links:
    - rabbitmq:rabbit
    volumes:
    - C:\Develop\vsts_tfs\Service2:/app:rw
    - C:\Users\MYUSER\vsdbg:/remote_debugger:ro
    - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages:ro
    - C:\Users\MYUSER\.nuget\packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
```

My Service2 needs to get some console input, so I need to press "enter" in an interactive console. Unfortunately I don't get any console window to open - but I see the output of my Service2 in the Debug-Window telling me to press enter - I just can't press enter.

Regarding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856823/where-is-the-linux-console-output-when-using-remote-debug-with-visual-studio-201), for C++-projects there is a so called "Linux Console" in the Debug-Menu - but I don't have this button. I also tried to get it by installing the "Visual C++ for Linux-Development"-Feature, but it didn't help.

This is how my Debug-Menu looks like:
[image: No Linux Console button]
Any ideas how I can open a console window to control the application inside my docker-container?

Just as a **side note**: The application waiting for enter is just for development purposes, as it sends commands to the RabbitMQ-pipeline without the usage of the web-frontend. It would be possible to start this outside of docker, but it would destroy the comfort of "running them all by pressing one button" (and without setting multiple startup projects) and would add a mixture of docker- and non-docker-components to my solution.

Comment: which service is waiting for the input in this case? `service1` or `service2`?

Comment: It's Service2. I also tried swapping Service1 with Service2 in the docker-compose file without any success.

Comment: @Compufreak did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remember how I solved this 3 years ago and I can't find the project anymore to look it up. I probably did not find a solution as I otherwise should have posted it as a response here. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

**PS: Using comments as answer for now since I need formatting**

You need make 2 changes to your docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    image: service1
    build:
      context: ./Service1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
     - "rabbitmq:rabbit"
  service2:
    image: service2
    build:
      context: ./Service2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
     - "rabbitmq:rabbit"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
     - "8082:15672"
     - "5672:5672"
```

Now `docker-compose` doesn't support taking input from stdin and passing it to the container, so there is no way you can continue the session from debug console. You need to run another terminal and run

```
docker attach <foldername>_service2_1
```

Basically you need to give the name or id of the container. Then you press enter the container will continue further

Comment: Thanks for this answer, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work together with the Visual Studio debugger as it puts an `entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null` into the docker-compose-file and starts the process by injecting some kind of command into the docker-container, so docker attach probably grabs the tail -f /dev/null and not my application :/

Comment: Can you post the override yml also in the question?

Comment: My override.yml just contains `version:3`, I think you are asking for the one Visual Studio uses. I added the Docker-Output from Visual Studio to my question, it should contain what you asked for.

Comment: That would make this even more complex, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process

Comment: This looked so promising, but alas, I ran into the same problem as @Compufreak. I'm not able to attach to a .Net Core Console container that's started by Visual Studio.